# Cache issues in Telerik Reporting in MAUI Blazor

Tags: telerik, reporting, telerik-reporting, maui-blazor

I have created Blazor (.Net7) MAUI Windows application and used Telerik Reporting for Reports.

```
    @if (SourceOptions != null)
            {
                <ReportViewer ViewerId="ReportView"
                          ServiceUrl="@ReportSetting.ReportRestServicePath"
                          ReportSource="@SourceOptions"
                          Parameters="@(new ParametersOptions { Editors = new EditorsOptions { MultiSelect = EditorType.ComboBox, SingleSelect = EditorType.ComboBox } })"
                          ScaleMode="@(ScaleMode.Specific)"
                          @ref="__refReportViewer"
                          ParametersAreaVisible=false
                          Scale="1.0" />
            }
    @code{
        [Parameter] public TerlrikReportOptions ReportSetting { get; set; }

        [Parameter] public EventCallback CloseReportDelegate { get; set; }

        private ReportSourceOptions SourceOptions;

        private ReportViewer __refReportViewer;

        public BLReportViewer()
        {
        }

        protected override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
        {
            SourceOptions = new ReportSourceOptions();
            SourceOptions.Report = ReportSetting.ReportName;
            SourceOptions.Parameters = ReportSetting.ReportParameters;
            return base.OnParametersSetAsync();
        }
}
```

I am using this as a separate razor component by passing some parameters from the parent razor file. But quite often the reports that we are showing on this Telerik report viewer have some issues. Sometimes time to time report data are not showing, a blank page only can see. Sometimes header and footer of the page are only showing but the content has been missed. Even if the report doesn't have any issues, some report-building errors are showing in the red color text box.

Always I have to close the application and open it again and reload the report. After that, any issues were not there and all are working fine. Most of the time we are getting this issue when we publish a new version of it and install it for the very first time. From my point of view, I think it should be a cache issue.